# Does ProxyAttribute work properly in Mono?

Tags: mono

I'm attempting to get an existing .NET application working on Mono.  The application was created with VS 2010 (not with Mono development tools), and I'm using Mono 2.10.6 on Windows 7.

The application has a class that's annotated with a subclass of ProxyAttribute (actually, System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.ProxyAttribute).  In regular .NET, when the annotated class is instantiated, the ProxyAttribute's CreateInstance() method executes before the annotated class's constructor executes, as it should.  When run on Mono, the CreateInstance() method doesn't execute.  Everything else up to that point seems to work properly.

The Mono documentation does show that ProxyAttribute is available in Mono, and I haven't found anything in my searches to suggest that there should be a problem.

Does anyone know of any known problem here?  Alternatively, should I be invoking Mono with some additional option? Currently I'm simply issuing the command:

mono myApplication.exe

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the class is there, the feature is not currently supported in Mono.
You may want to file a bug in bugzilla.xamarin.com with a complete simple test case so that eventually we may implement it.

Comment: lupus -- Thanks for the prompt response.  That helps me know where I need to direct my attention.